# libgit2sharp unable to push tag with tagger and date?

Tags: git, lib2gitsharp

We are trying to push **annotated** tags to remote using `libgit2` but for some reason we are loosing information on the tag somewhere in the process.

Step 1: create apply a new tag

```
// Left out username and email address for obvious reasons :)
var createdTag = _repository.ApplyTag(tag, new Signature("***", "***", DateTimeOffset.Now), tagMessage);
```

Verify this works through commandline:

```
C:\Users\bpr\AppData\Local\Temp\TempTestFolder(DocumentDefinition_CardType1_Development -> origin)                           
λ git show DocumentDefinition_CardType1_1.0.4                                                                                
tag DocumentDefinition_CardType1_1.0.4                                                                                       
Tagger: *** <***@***>                                                                                   
Date:   Thu Oct 19 16:06:47 2023 +0200                                                                                       
                                                                                                                             
some tag description                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                             
commit 517791ef219bc74724f7b3fea041923517be4c0c (HEAD -> DocumentDefinition_CardType1_Development, tag: DocumentDefinition_CardType1_1.0.4, origin/DocumentDefinition_CardType1_Development)                                                                                       
Author: *** <***@***>                                                                                   
Date:   Thu Oct 19 13:40:44 2023 +0200                                                                                       
                                                                                                                             
    test3                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                             
diff --git a/test3.txt b/test3.txt                                                                                           
new file mode 100644                                                                                                         
index 0000000..df6b0d2                                                                                                       
--- /dev/null                                                                                                                
+++ b/test3.txt                                                                                                              
@@ -0,0 +1 @@                                                                                                                
+test3
```

Then, the local tag will be pushed to origin

```
var remote = _repository.Network.Remotes[Origin];
var credentials = _gitCredentialsResolver();

_repository.Network.Push(
    remote, 
    createdTag.Target.Sha,
    createdTag.CanonicalName,
    new PushOptions
    {
        CredentialsProvider = (_, _, _) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
        {
            Username = credentials.UserName, Password = credentials.Password.ConvertToPlainText()
        }
    });
```

Since we are testing our functionality with our existing git repo in bitbucket, we can now see that bitbucket doesn't accept this tag as an **annotated tag** but it became a light weight tag for some reason.

[image]

Here, the tag "blabla" was created from the bitbucket UI, and is shown as an annotated tag, with a tagger, and a date. All other tags, are created through libgit2sharp, WITH a tagger and WITH a date, but still show as light weight tags. Why?

When I clone this repository and show the tag there, I can also see that the information of tagger and date no longer is present. So it got lost, somewhere, but I can't figure out where, or why.

Hoping somebody from the libgit2sharp team, or anybody who might know what is going on here, can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

We found the culprit...

```
_repository.Network.Push(
    remote, 
    createdTag.Target.Sha, // Removing this, solved the problem (no clue why, but at this point I also don't really care anymore:)
    createdTag.CanonicalName,
    new PushOptions
    {
        CredentialsProvider = (_, _, _) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
        {
            Username = credentials.UserName, Password = credentials.Password.ConvertToPlainText()
        }
    });
```